# How to group output rows based on date either on mySQL or PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

The following query returns some rows, that each one has its own `date_created`.

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 l 
       inner join table2 d 
               ON d.id = l.id 
WHERE  l.company_id = 1

UNION ALL 

SELECT * 
FROM   table1 l 
       inner join table3 p 
               ON p.id = l.id 
WHERE  p.company_id = 1
```

**sample output:**

```
company_id ---- user_id ---- text ---- dateAndTime
1          ----  abc    ----  hi  ---- 2017-08-17 22:26:18
1          ----  def    ----  hey ---- 2017-08-08 11:57:26
1          ----  abc    ----  hi  ---- 2017-08-08 11:55:40
1          ----  ghz    ----  sup ---- 2017-07-25 16:01:34
```

**What I want to achieve:**

I am running a php foreach loop to display all of these data. However on each date change, I want to display the date (like groupping them design-wise).

So the output (on display)

```
2017-08-17
    1          ----  abc    ----  hi  ---- 2017-08-17 22:26:18
2017-08-08
    1          ----  def    ----  hey ---- 2017-08-08 11:57:26
    1          ----  abc    ----  hi  ---- 2017-08-08 11:55:40
2017-07-25
    1          ----  ghz    ----  sup ---- 2017-07-25 16:01:34
```

How can I achieve this either with mySQL or PHP?

Comment: Use `ORDER BY DATE(dateAndTime)` in your query.  Handle the rest of your output in PHP.  Have you written any PHP code yet?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have this ordering to be honest, however the PHP part is where it lacks. One idea I was trying to do, is to save the `previous` date from the foreach loop, but it can not stand logically. at least in my mind.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @EnexoOnoma That's exactly right.  Then, print that date header only when you hit a record where that date header changes.

Comment: What If there is another `company_id` with same date, what   is output design then ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze this will not be the case because the results are only for one company (there will be no conflict between companies)

Comment: Ah, I missed `...WHERE  l.company_id = 1` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the last date in a variable, check in every iteration:

```
$q = "SELECT company_id, user_id, text, dateAndTime, DATE(dateAndTime) as date FROM   table1 l inner join table2 d ON d.id = l.id WHERE  l.company_id = 1 UNION ALL SELECT company_id, user_id, text, dateAndTime, DATE(dateAndTime) as date FROM   table1 l inner join table3 p ON p.id = l.id WHERE  p.company_id = 1";
// ...
$lastGroupDate = null;
foreach ($row as $company) {
    if ($lastGroupDate !== $company["date"]) {
        echo $company["date"]."<br>";
    }
    echo $company["user_id"]."<br>";
    // rest of fields
    $lastGroupDate = $company["date"];
}
```

Remember to sort the results by dateAndTime in the query.

Important: you need to get `DATE(dateAndTime) as date` in the query too, since you need to group them by only date (not time).